# How to get bootstrap background image carousel navigation working?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've just rebuilt the bootstrap carousel so it displays background images in the slider. The problem is in this case I can't get the navigation working. I put the indicators and navigation outside the carousel itself, because inside it was not responding at all. 
Could anyone please help? The link is szmida.nazwa.pl/mauri/

```html
    <header>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
       <!-- Indicators -->
       <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div style="background: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/mauri1.jpg'; ?>);" class="active item one"></div>
            <div style="background: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/mauri2.jpg'; ?>);" class="item two"></div>
            <div style="background: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/mauri3.jpg'; ?>);" class="item three"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="wrapp">
     <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
     <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li  data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
         <li  data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
         <li  data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
     </ol>

     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 si">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <!--<div id="logo">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/logo.png'; ?>" />
                </div>-->
                       <div class="navbar-header">
                         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                           <h5>menu</h5>
                         </button>
                       </div>

                       <?php
                       wp_nav_menu( array(
                           'menu'              => 'Header Menu',
                           'theme_location'    => 'menu_header',
                           'depth'             => 2,
                           'container'         => 'div',
                           'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                           'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                           'menu_class'        => 'menu',
                           'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                           'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                       );
                       ?>

                   </nav>
                   <div class="logo_duze">
                       <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/logo_duze.png'; ?>" />
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div> 
</header>
```

Comment: Maybe your still working on it, but it looks like the navigation is working. URL's are changing, and after the carousel you can see the page title. Is the carousel supposed to be in the header? It will show up in every page the way you have it.

Comment: Robert II meant the carousel itself navigation, I cant get the slides change after clicking >< signs.